# How properly define Spring Integration JpaOutboundGateway in Java Configuration?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-integration

I'm trying to replace Spring Integration XML configuration by JavaConfig and I can't properly define JpaOutboundGateway. In XML i have following bean definition:

```
<int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter id="saveOffer" entity-manager-factory="entityManagerFactory" channel="channel5"
                                  flush-size="100" entity-class="JobOffer">
    <int-jpa:transactional transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

And it works fine. But when I'm trying to move it to java config bean I don't know how to define transaction management... I'm still getting errors connected with transactions.

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="channel5")
public JpaOutboundGatewayFactoryBean save() throws Exception {

    JpaExecutor executor = new JpaExecutor(entityManager);
    executor.setFlushSize(10);
    executor.setEntityClass(JobOffer.class);

    JpaOutboundGatewayFactoryBean factoryBean = new JpaOutboundGatewayFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setJpaExecutor(executor);
    factoryBean.setProducesReply(false);

    return factoryBean;
}
```

I was trying to use EntityManager and EntityManagerFactory in JpaExecutor. But in both cases exception is thrown:

```
2016-09-03 09:20:42.440 ERROR o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler  : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.jpa.outbound.JpaOutboundGateway@1fc306d3]; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'merge' call
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:139)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.PollingConsumer.handleMessage(PollingConsumer.java:129)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:272)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:344)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'merge' call
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:282)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.merge(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.jpa.core.DefaultJpaOperations.persistOrMerge(DefaultJpaOperations.java:248)
    at org.springframework.integration.jpa.core.DefaultJpaOperations.merge(DefaultJpaOperations.java:215)
    at org.springframework.integration.jpa.core.JpaExecutor.executeOutboundJpaOperation(JpaExecutor.java:253)
    at org.springframework.integration.jpa.outbound.JpaOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(JpaOutboundGateway.java:81)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the more complicated endpoints to wire up; we need to add an example for Java configuration to the reference manual; I opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4106).

You can always look at [the XML parser](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-jpa/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/jpa/config/xml/JpaOutboundChannelAdapterParser.java#L82) to see what's needed.

In particular:

1. the `JpaExecutor` should be defined as as `@Bean`.
2. You need to add a transaction advice to the adapter's `txAdviceChain`.
3. You can look at `IntegrationNamespaceUtils.configureTransactionAttributes` to see what's needed to wire up the transaction advice (transaction attribute, attribute source, TM, etc) wired into a `TransactionInterceptor`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried to analyze XML parser before asking question here, but I didn't understand those transaction advice chain things... But maybe with your suggestion I will make it work.

Comment: My "ugly-but-working" version is in next answer. I admit that is far less intuitive that i've expected...

Comment: Certainly one benefit of using XML - the parser does a lot for you. For java configuration, when we add JPA support to the [Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl) it will be a little easier to configure. The DSL is being rolled into the main project in 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

My "ugly-but-working" version:

```
@Bean
public JpaExecutor jpaExecutor() {

    JpaExecutor executor = new JpaExecutor(entityManagerFactory);
    executor.setFlushSize(10);
    executor.setEntityClass(JobOffer.class);
    return executor;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="channel5")
public JpaOutboundGateway save(JpaExecutor jpaExecutor, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) throws Exception {

    DefaultTransactionAttribute dta = new DefaultTransactionAttribute();
    dta.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
    dta.setReadOnly(false);

    MatchAlwaysTransactionAttributeSource matas = new MatchAlwaysTransactionAttributeSource();
    matas.setTransactionAttribute(dta);

    TransactionInterceptor ic = new TransactionInterceptor();
    ic.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    ic.setTransactionAttributeSource(matas);

    List<Advice> adviceChain = new ArrayList<>();
    adviceChain.add(ic);

    JpaOutboundGateway gateway = new JpaOutboundGateway(jpaExecutor);
    gateway.setAdviceChain(adviceChain);
    gateway.setProducesReply(false);

    return gateway;
}
```